# How do I develop mobile friendly html pages?

Tags: html

I have an existing website that I would like it to be transformed into mobile version. How can I do so? Do I have to create an entire different version of application. Do I have to write everything from scratch by changing logic etc? I am quiet confused.

Please give me few pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) JQuery Mobile will help. I'm not sure if you use much javascript/jquery on your page, but using the JQuery Mobile version will help with making sure it works on mobiles.
http://jquerymobile.com/

2) Assigning a separate CSS to mobile only will help. You can try to remove big margins/padding and font settings. Maybe have different images set so they can be smaller if this CSS if chosen.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css" media="handheld" />
```

I highly recommend the use of JQuery Mobile, as it has great documentation to help you out. The use of the handheld css is also handy, as you can get rid of spacing and font issues you may not have on larger screens.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use `@media` queries in `css`.
or just use some mobile ui library like ant-design-mobile or something else, then your website is automatically mobile friendly

Answer (score -1):

... just came across this on [dzone](http://dzone.com): http://foundation.zurb.com/index.php

Looks interesting, might be worth checking out in addition jQuerymobile